# ROS Answers SE migration: create .launch

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

how can i create a .launch file? is there anywhere a useful tutorial or something?

thx in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41679/create-.launch/) by [shane](https://answers.ros.org/users/3039/shane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tut here too  - http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML at it's simplest at launch file will look like:

```
<launch>
 <node name="talker" pkg="rospy_tutorials" type="talker" />
</launch>
```

Remember that a launch file will start roscore for you - if one doesn't already exist.

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2012-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRxconsoleRoslaunch

But maybe you should do the tutorials here in order to get a general overview:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-08-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3